# check if nested list is binary search tree

Tags: python, tree

I am trying to implement function that checks if nested list is binary search tree

for e.g `[50, [44, 30, 48], [80, [66, 60, 67], 88]]` i have this list that presents tree
tree is presented using this logic

```
# Tree in nested list
tree1 = ['a', ['b', ['d',[],[]], ['e',[],[]] ], ['c', ['f',[],[]], []] ]
#
tree2 = ['a',         #root
      ['b',             #left subtree
       ['d', [], []],   #left child of b - empty lists show that there are no children
       ['e', [], []] ], #right child of b
      ['c',             #right subtree
       ['f', [], []],
       [] ]
     ]
```

Is there any easy, obvious way to do this. I am fairly new to python and data structures

I tried writing it by using function is_bst

```
def is_bsp(list)     
    root = lists[0]
        cur_value = 0
        level = 0
        for i in lists:
            print(i)
            if isinstance(i, list):
                is_bsp(i)
```

But I dont know how to continue using this

input/output example

```
is_bsp([50, [44, 30, 48], [80, [66, 60, 67], 88]])
=> True

is_bsp([50, [44, 30, 48], [49, [66, 60, 67], 88]])
=> False
```

Answer (score 0):

I would flatten the tree to a sequence and then check if the result is sorted.

```
def flatten_tree(lst):
    if not isinstance(lst, (list, tuple)):
        return [lst]
    if not lst:
        return []
    if len(lst) != 3:
        raise ValueError(f"expected is [root, left, right], got {lst}")
    return [*flatten_tree(lst[1]), lst[0], *flatten_tree(lst[2])]

def is_bsp(tree):
    # TODO: if empty: return True
    try:
        lst = flatten_tree(tree)
        return all(a <= b for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]))    # is sorted?
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return False
```

The code above does not handle an empty tree (don't know how is it represented) and does not check for circular references (a malicious input could trigger an endless recursion).

Comment: But in this example [50, [44, 30, 48], [80, [66, 60, 67], 88]] if I flatten this list i will get [50, 44, 30, 48, 80, 66, 60, 67, 88] and that is not sorted array but it is binary tree soo my result wont be correct

Comment: The posted code produces `[30, 44, 48, 50, 60, 66, 67, 80, 88]` for the given list. It is not a simple list flattening. It recursively transform `[root, left_tree, right_tree]` --> `[left_tree_flattened, root, right_tree_flattened]`

Comment: After running your code i got this error: ValueError: expected is [root, left, right], got [80, [66, 60, 67], 88, [21, 2]]